# Ellipse fill issues with listview WP8.1 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am wanting the position of the item in list to appear to left of the description but for some reason its making my font messed up and placing it in the center as shown in image. I am just wanting to mimic the same image I have on the map so it coresponds to listview poistion.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextListInboxTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="470" Height="85">
            <Border Height="40" Width="40" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">

                <Grid Width="40" Height="40">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"  StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding _position}"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Semilight" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="320" Height="26" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _Name}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Semilight" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="320" Height="26" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _Postcode}" 
                       Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="320" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sed varius rhoncus metus, et condimentum" 
                       Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="320" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="00:00 AM" FontSize="9" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
```

With Circle as above
[image]

Without circle by just removing the following code

```
<Grid Width="40" Height="40">
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue"  StrokeThickness="3"/>
                <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding _position}"/>
            </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your containing stack panel is fixed at Height="85".  Because it's a vertical stack panel it will add items to the control vertically, so you're specifying:

- a StackPanel with a 10 top margin;
- a Grid of height 40;
- an empty TextBlock of height 26;

leaving 9 pixels for your _Name TextBlock, hence the clipping of the TextBlock and everything under it you're seeing there.

There's a number of ways you could get your ellipse grid to the left of one of the text boxes, I would probably consider wrapping a grid around the textblock you want it to be displayed to the left of like this:

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"  StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding _position}"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sed varius rhoncus metus, et condimentum" 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="320" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
```